# How to use Python ldap3 Kerberos authentication on Linux without editing any config files?

Tags: python, linux, ldap, kerberos, ldap3

How can I log into an LDAP server with a Kerberos username and password without making any changes to the configuration of the computer that the Python script is running on? [The ldap3 documentation](https://ldap3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bind.html#kerberos) assumes that Kerberos has already been set up by editing `/etc/krb5.conf` and running `kinit`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the environment variable `KRB5_CONFIG` to specify a temporary config file and the `acquire_cred_with_password` function to construct a credentials object to pass to the LDAP connection. Use the following example:

```
import gssapi
import os
from ldap3 import *
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

controller = 'mydomaincontroller'
realm = 'MYDOMAIN.COM'
username = 'myuser'
password = 'mypassword'

conf = f'''
[libdefaults]
    default_realm = {realm}

[realms]
    {realm} = {{
        kdc = {controller}.{realm}
        admin_server = {controller}.{realm}
        default_domain = {realm}
    }}
'''
print(conf)

with NamedTemporaryFile() as f:
    f.write(conf.encode())
    f.flush()

    os.environ['KRB5_CONFIG'] = f.name

    user = gssapi.Name(base=username, name_type=gssapi.NameType.user)
    creds = gssapi.raw.acquire_cred_with_password(user, password.encode()).creds

    server = Server(f'{controller}.{realm}')
    conn = Connection(server, authentication=SASL, sasl_mechanism=KERBEROS,
                      sasl_credentials=(None, None, creds))
    conn.bind()

print(conn)
print(conn.extend.standard.who_am_i())
```

Note that the relam must be all uppercase, and the realm and the domain are the same in this example. `mydomaincontroller.mydomain.com` must be defined in DNS or in `/etc/hosts`.

The documentation for the `sasl_credentials` argument is in the [ldap3 source code](https://github.com/cannatag/ldap3/blob/040e09fe37cf06801960d494dfadf0a6ed94e38f/ldap3/protocol/sasl/kerberos.py#L88).

Answer (score 0):

Ask your realm administrator to add proper DNS SRV records pointing at your KDCs:

```
_kerberos._tcp  SRV  10  0  88  kdc1
_kerberos._tcp  SRV  10  0  88  kdc2
```

This will let krb5 clients automatically find KDCs without manual client-side configuration. (All Active Directory domains have such records; it's not a new feature at all.)

In place of configuring default_realm, specify the realm as part of the "username" (i.e. the full Kerberos principal in `user@REALM` format).